# Sample from a 2d probability numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Say that I have an 2d array `ar` like this:

```
0.9, 0.1, 0.3
0.4, 0.5, 0.1
0.5, 0.8, 0.5
```

And I want to sample from [1, 0] according to this probability array.

```py
rdchoice = lambda x: numpy.random.choice([1, 0], p=[x, 1-x])
```

I have tried two methods:

1) reshape it into a 1d array first and use `numpy.random.choice` and then reshape it back to 2d:

```py
np.array(list(map(rdchoice, ar.reshape((-1,))))).reshape(ar.shape)
```

2) use the vectorize function.

```py
func = numpy.vectorize(rdchoice)
func(ar)
```

But these two ways are all too slow, and I learned that the nature of the vectorize is a for-loop and in my experiments, I found that `map` is no faster than `vectorize`.

I thought this can be done faster. If the 2d array is large it would be unbearably slow.

Comment: How fast is `np.reshape([np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[x, 1-x]) for x in arr.flat], arr.shape)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this like so:

```
>>> p = np.array([[0.9, 0.1, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.1], [0.5, 0.8, 0.5]])
>>> (np.random.rand(*p.shape) < p).astype(int)
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks very much. A follow-up. I wonder if any futher optimation would be possible if the samples are not [0, 1], say it is [-1, 1]. I know I can just add an additional step by first scaling it and then add a value: Y=2*X-1. But is it possible to do it in one step? What if the samples are arbitrary like [23, 15]?

Comment: @lerner `np.where(np.random.random(p.shape) < p, 23, 15)`

Answer (score -1):

Actually I can use the [np.random.binomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html):

```
import numpy as np
p = [[0.9, 0.1, 0.3],
     [0.4, 0.5, 0.1],
     [0.5, 0.8, 0.5]]

np.random.binomial(1, p)
```